# Give access to gitlab repo to s.o. from outside - but only this person

Tags: gitlab

I am having a gitlab account at an organisation. I can make repositories, but I can not add users or anything. I have a repository with code in it that I am allowed to share. However, I do not want to share the code with anyone, so I do not want to make this one repository in question public. I only want to share it with one person that is not part of our organisation. I can not create an account for that person. Can I give that person access to this one repository without opening it for the whole world and how can I do this?

Preferable, I'd upload a public key for the repository.

Comment: You can add that person to the organization and then give access since it's not illegal

Comment: I try to clarify, please see my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yust make your repository private and add your friend's public key to the keys. That's it.